# Connection reset by peer on Azure

Tags: neo4j, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a web application running on an App Service on Azure cloud. 
On the back-end I'm using a tcp connection to our database (Neo4j graph db), the best practice is to open the tcp connection and keep it alive in order to be more reactive when we perform queries.

The issue I encountered is that the database is logging the exception "Connection reset by peer";
reading on the web I found out that maybe Azure has a TCP timeout configured by default, I read it to be set up to 4 minutes, which could be my issue root cause.

Someone knows how to configure the tcp KEEP ALIVE to always for App Services on Azure?
I found on the web how to do it in Google cloud but nothing about Azure cloud.

Thank you in advance.
OaicStef

Comment: In Azure - the only setting I'm aware of is the 'Always On' radio buttons in the 'Configuration' section of an App Service - it's under the 'General Settings' tab at the top - is that what you're after?

Comment: Nop, I'm aware of that setting and I have it already enabled. Thanks for your insight, anyway, I hope that some Azure guru will read this post.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem, I have a similar issue that the connection got reset around a 4 four minutes time window and it is one quite persistent error...

Answer (score 1):

From everything I can find that is not an adjustable setting. Here is the forum link that says it will not be changing and that is a couple years old at this point. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32b76114-67a4-4e6b-ac45-61b0f0a0829f/changing-the-4-minute-request-time-out-for-app-services?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

I think you are going to have to add logic to your app that tests the connection, if it has been closed then either reopen it or create a new one. I don't know what language you are using to make any suggestions there.

### Edit

I will add that the total number of TCP connections that can be open on a single App Service is about 6k, at least on the S1. Keep that in mind because if you don't have pooling on the server side or you are not disposing of those then you will exhaust that the TCP pool and you will start getting errors. I recommend you configure an alert for that.